# how can I load my scenes without the error [scene has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

I have an error of scene that couldn't be loaded.

I have two scenes. I change my current scene if the requested scene from my server is not the same but it is not loaded.

> Scene '/Assets/Beach_Essentials/DemoScene' couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded.
> To add a scene to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings...
> UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager:LoadScene (string)

But my scenes are in Build settings.

Has anyone had an issue like this, please?

I get the name of the requested scene from my json defined like this:

```cs
    requested_scene = root["item"]["asset"]; 
    private void Update()
        {
            // Check if the name of the current Active Scene is your first Scene.
            if(requested_scene != "")
            {
                Debug.Log("Try to load scene "+requested_scene);
                Scene current_scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
                if(current_scene.name != requested_scene)
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(requested_scene);
                    Debug.Log("Scene loaded"+requested_scene);
                }
            }
    //rest of the code
    }
```

[image: build setting capture]

[image: the error]

Do you think that I have to make my scenes in the regular environment or UI environment presented in the picture below:

[image: project-settings]

Comment: Can you show your code that loads the scene and take a screenshot of the `Build settings` menu?

Comment: Also make sure you **CHECKED** the scene checkbox in the Build settings menu.

Comment: i edited my code, i have added it

Comment: `how can I load my scenes without the error [scene has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded]` => I'd say by either adding it to the build settings or load the Asset bundle correctly ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the value of the `requested_scene`.

You put the **FULL PATH** (`/Assets/Beach_Essentials/DemoScene`) in the `requested_scene` variable. Just add the name of the scene to your variable.

Like this:

```cs
requested_scene = "DemoScene";
SceneManager.LoadScene(requested_scene);
```

Comment: yes i put the full path and it  is worked thank you!